# One function for two buttons (increment, decrement)

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to increment and also decrement a value (5) and I would like to cover this with one function (I know how to do it with two).
Unfortunately I am not able to get it done and can't figure out what is wrong.

Here is my code:
HTML:

```
<form>
  <button type="button" value="minus" onclick="updateAmount();">
    -  
  </button>
  <span id="number">
    5
  </span>
  <button type="button" value="plus" onclick="updateAmount();">
    +  
  </button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
var num = parseInt(document.getElementById('number');
var btn = document.querySelector('button');

btn.addEventListener('click', updateAmount);

function updateAmount(){    
    btn.value === "minus" ? num-- : num++;  
  document.getElementById('number').value = num;
}
```

Also at [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/phantazee/3Lw1e6hc/)

I would prefer a vanilla JS solution if possible, but any suggestion is welcome :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this ...

```
   <html>
       <form>
          <button type="button" value="minus" onclick="updateAmount(this.value);">
          -  
      </button>
      <span id="number">
       5
     </span>
    <button type="button" value="plus" onclick="updateAmount(this.value);">
     +  
   </button>    
  </form>
  <script>
    function updateAmount(value){ 
     var num = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').innerHTML);
    value=='plus'?num++:num--;
    document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = num;
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The minimal-changes to your approach is to pass an argument to the function:

```js
function updateAmount(value) {
  console.log("Update it by: " + value);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <button type="button" value="minus" onclick="updateAmount(-1);">
    -  
  </button>
  <span id="number">
    5
  </span>
  <button type="button" value="plus" onclick="updateAmount(1);">
    +  
  </button>
</form>
```

Or use your `value` attribute and pass `this` into the function:

```js
function updateAmount(btn) {
  var value = btn.value == "minus" ? -1 : 1;
  console.log("Update it by: " + value);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <button type="button" value="minus" onclick="updateAmount(this);">
    -  
  </button>
  <span id="number">
    5
  </span>
  <button type="button" value="plus" onclick="updateAmount(this);">
    +  
  </button>
</form>
```

That latter approach combines nicely with modern event handling:

```js
// Scoping function so our `updateAmount` isn't global
(function() {
  document.querySelector("button[value=minus]").addEventListener("click", updateAmount);
  document.querySelector("button[value=plus]").addEventListener("click", updateAmount);
  
  function updateAmount() {
    var value = this.value == "minus" ? -1 : 1;
    console.log("Update it by: " + value);
  }
})();
```

```html
<form>
  <button type="button" value="minus">
    -  
  </button>
  <span id="number">
    5
  </span>
  <button type="button" value="plus">
    +  
  </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could hand over the action as a parameter

```
<form>
  <button type="button" value="minus" onclick="updateAmount('minus');">
    -  
  </button>
  <span id="number">
    5
  </span>
  <button type="button" value="plus" onclick="updateAmount('plus');">
    +  
  </button>
</form>
```

and then

```
function updateAmount(action) {
   var num = parseInt(document.getElementById("number").innerHTML, 10);
   switch(action) {
      case 'minus':
         num--;
         break;
      case 'plus':
         num++;
         break;
   }
   document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close, as you have multiple elements use `document.querySelectorAll()` with valid selector to get there reference and bind event handlers.

As you are using `<SPAN>` element, it doesn't have `value` property, need to use `textContent` property.

```js
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('button');
btns.forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', updateAmount);
});

function updateAmount() {
  var num = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').textContent.trim(), 10);
  this.value === "minus" ? num-- : num++;
  document.getElementById('number').textContent = num;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" value="minus">-</button>
<span id="number">5</span>
<button type="button" value="plus">+</button>
```

Note: Get rid of ugly inline click handlers.

Answer (score 0):

simply use like this `updateAmount(this)`

```js
function updateAmount(that) {
var number = document.getElementById('number');
  var num = parseInt(number.innerHTML);
  num = (that.value == "minus") ? --num : ++num;
  number.innerHTML = num;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <button type="button" value="minus" onclick="updateAmount(this);">
    -  
  </button>
  <span id="number">
    5
  </span>
  <button type="button" value="plus" onclick="updateAmount(this);">
    +  
  </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var minusBtn = document.querySelector('#minus');
var plusBtn = document.querySelector('#plus');

minusBtn.addEventListener('click', updateAmount('minus'));
plusBtn.addEventListener('click', updateAmount('plus'));

function updateAmount(action) {
  return function() {
   var numberElem = document.getElementById('number');
   var number = numberElem.innerText;
   number = parseInt(number, 10);
   if (action === 'minus') {
     number--;
   } else if(action === 'plus') {
     number++;
   } else {
     throw new Error('invalid operator');
   }
   numberElem.innerText = number;
 };
}


<form>
 <button id = "minus" type="button" value="minus">
  -  
 </button>
 <span id="number">
  5
 </span>
 <button id = "plus" type="button" value="plus">
  +  
 </button>
</form>
```

this is a good example for curry function, you can currify your updateAmount to accept action as a part of argument

Answer (score 0):

Your code has just two small flaw, rest is perfect. 
Firstly Your variable **num** is evaluating to **NaN**.
Secondly you should use **textContent** instead of **value** .
I am sharing correct way to evaluate num and then it will work.

```
var el =document.getElementById('number')
var num = parseInt(el.textContent);
```

Again, while updating

```
document.getElementById('number').textContent = num
```

Hope it helped.